# Undefined Index? Php/HTML Form

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

Can't for the life of me seem to figure out what the problem is here, but I have quite a simple form that submits data to a database and displays it on the screen.
Every part of the form submits perfectly except for the "textarea" (message)

Comment: What's up with `form="reasoning"`?

Comment: Tip: Don't use `die(mysql_error())` in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `form="reasoning"` fixed it here.

Also, just FYI there is a stray quotation mark (and a missing one) in your `<option>` values.

Comment: Silly me! Thanks for the response, but after changing that I'm now getting the following error;  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: How many columns are in your table? As you haven't specified the columns you're inserting to, they have to match exactly.

I would do it more like this: `INSERT INTO feedback (name, subject, text) VALUES ('$name', '$subject', '$text')`

Comment: I've got 5 columns, id (auto inc), name subject and comment (plus timestamp)

Comment: You will need to define the columns you want to insert to then, see the edited version of my comment above.

Comment: I'm now getting Error: Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' omfg lol

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use: placeholder="General Feedback" it's more customer friendly then value.
Just a tip because CalamityJames already gave the good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sevo, this will be used by a machine using IE6 :(

Comment: Pity, it's supported in IE10.
You've solved your problem already?

Answer (score 0):

This one is incomplete:

> option value=**New Call Reason**">New Call Reason

Also remove the

> form="reasoning".

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use something like:

$sql = "INSERT INTO feedback (name,subject,comment) VALUES (:name,:subject,:comment)";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':name'=>$name,
                      ':subject'=>$subject,
                          ':comment'=>$comment
                           ));

I would certainly recommend PDO.